# VBA Sort & Hide Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro I use to sort and hide fields inside a table, however the users who utilize this don't all have the same fields or even in the same place:

User 1 "Order" is column B but User 2 "Order" is column D. When I made the macro I made it with how my fields are setup in hopes that by using a table that the macro would sort and hide based on the names. (I was wrong) I only need 2 fields left showing "DriverNo" and "POD Name". I also need to sort by "DriverNo"

I don't have to hide the data I can delete it but I use column AI as a compliance field for the drivers: 
`=SUMIFS('Order Data'!AI:AI,'Order Data'!C:C,A:A)`

So If I delete the fields the same column would have to be free to calculate my compliance. I know it's a lot, but I'm stuck. I don't know how to ensure only those fields are hidden / removed. Removed would be preferred.

`Sub Sort()
'
' Sort Macro
'
    Sheets("Order Data").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("C1:C403"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A:B,K:Z,D:I").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub Sort_Hide()
'
' Sort_Hide Macro
'
Sheets("Order Data").Activate
  Range("A1").Value = 35
Sheets("Order Data").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("D5").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[[#All],[DriverNo]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").ListObjects("Table2").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("D:N,P:AH").Select
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],['[D'] Arrival]]").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("O9").Select
End Sub`

Comment: Sounds like you will have to search for column names you intend to hide/delete or sort on.  This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686841/find-column-header-by-name-and-select-all-data-below-column-header-excel-vba) will help with that endevor.

Comment: This is where I am so far:

<code>Sub DeleteSelectedColumns()
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String
For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
'Check whether to preserve the column
    Select Case columnHeading
    'Insert name of columns to preserve
        Case "DriverNo", "POD Name"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
            'Delete the column
            ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        End Select
    Next
End Sub</code>

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1408277/edit) instead of adding information in comments (where large chunks of code are essentially unreadable)